# is there a way i can create a while loop to fetch only values greater then 0 dynamically and print the field and value?

Tags: php, mysql

```
// Connect to server and select databse.
$conn = mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysqli_select_db($conn,"$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

here i am selecting all data from the database 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tb2_name WHERE Month='$month' AND Year='$year' AND Employee_Number='$user'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);


    // output data of each row
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH);
$Tax_Num = $row['Tax_Number'];
    $Number = $row["Employee_Number"];
    $Payslip_Number = $row["Payslip_Number"];
    $Salary = $row["Salary"];
    $Bonus = $row["Bonus"];
    $Housing_Allowance = $row["Housing_Allowance"];
```

There problem comes when a column is created dynamically in the Database and thus will not be able to be defined manually .

is there a way i can create a while loop to fetch only values greater then 0 dynamically ?

Comment: What value needs to be greater than 0?  Also when you say dynamically, are you referring to now knowing all the columns because there might be some added?

Comment: a user can add a column via the user interface and therefore i might not know i all the columns but i still want to select all the columns even if i do not know the column exists but i only want to select columns where values are greater then 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve here, but perhaps you are thinking about this way too difficult. Do you mean something like this?

```
$sql = "
     SELECT 
       * 
     FROM 
        $tb2_name 
     WHERE 
        Month='$month' 
        AND 
        Year='$year' 
        AND 
        Employee_Number='$user'
";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$data = array();
foreach($rows as $key => $value) {
  if($value > 0) {
    echo $key . " => " . $value . "\n";
  }
}

#In $data there will be only database column values which are bigger than 6..
#Mmmm... still sounds like a strange request to me...
#Perhaps I interpreted your question wrong
```

Comment: yes i mean that but could you help me with the script to echo them under each other. ? will this script print the Field name and value next to it ?

Comment: I've updated my answer to fit your needs.. i guess :)